# How can I insert multiple lists as values into an AnyLogic database table?

Tags: anylogic

In order to record part IDs and process times for each agent, I created individual database tables where these values are recorded. I wanted to create a `results` database table to summarize all times and IDs in a single table. I tried writing the following code on model destroy to input the values on the individual tables into the results table:

```
List<String> list1 = selectFrom(identifiers).list(identifiers.part_id);
List<Double> list2 = selectFrom(cfs_time).list(cfs_time.cfs_time);
List<Double> list3 = selectFrom(deburr_time).list(deburr_time.deburr_time);
List<Double> list4 = selectFrom(drill_time).list(drill_time.drill_time);

insertInto( results )
.columns( results.part_id, results.cfs_time, results.deburr_time, results.drill_time) 
.values( list1, list2, list3, list4 )
.execute();
```

However when I run the model I get a **"row column count mismatch"** error on model destroy. When I try to input a single list (such as list1) with the following code:

```
insertInto( results )
.columns( results.part_id)
.values(list1)
.execute();
```

it works without any issue but obviously only adds a single column. This tells me that I am having a problem when I try to add multiple list like on the first code above. I wanted to ask what I am doing wrong with that code and what should I do differently to be able to input multiple lists into individual columns.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 4 lists have a different number of entries. Ensure they have the same `.size()` for the lists before writing them into the summary dbase table.

(this is what the error is trying to say as well :) )